# Software to edit Flash files

Tags: flash

I have Flash files that I would like to make edits on but I don't know how or with what.

Is there some software that can edit a Flash (.fla) file?

(Ideally something free.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the free 1 month trail version of [Adobe Flash CS4 Professional](https://www.adobe.com/products/flash/), which you can use to edit and create free flash movies. If all you need to do is a one-time editing of the flash (.fla) file, you can get away using just the trial version.

Answer (score 2):

Check [projects on osflash](http://www.osflash.org/projects). All of these are free. There are IDEs, command line tools, editors, game servers, etc

...and check [tutorials](http://osflash.org/tutorials).

Answer (score 2):

You can download the 30-day trial version of [Adobe Flash Professional](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/). I don't know of any free alternative that works as well.

Answer (score 1):

there are no legally free programs that allows full capable editing of Flash source files (.fla). Only Adobe Flash (not Player!) can do it.

I suggest you stop wasting time hoping a free program like this comes along, and start using that time saved to work and buy a copy eventually.

Comment: Well, maybe there is some free flash editing software you don't know

Comment: Harsh much?

Comment: No, Aaron, the .fla is supposedly a 'secret' file format and it would require reverse engineering Adobe's proprietary format in ways which is illegal in most countries.

Answer (score 1):

From the command-line, you may try [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) - SWF manipulation and generation utilities

You can install SWFTools distribution (which has also a command line program), and use [SWFExtract](http://www.swftools.org/swfextract.html), that can decompile flash files.

On OSX, install via: `brew install swftools`.